# Why do I keep getting: Cannot implicitly convert type string to type bool?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I cannot figure what is wrong with this code. I am creating a quiz and am trying to say well done if the answer is right but it keeps coming up with cannot implicitly turn type string to type bool.

Here is my code:

```
{
    int score = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(" What is your name?");
    string name = "";
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello " +name+ " and welcome to the Formula 1 quiz.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Question 1: How many races has Michael Schumacher won.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("a) 91");
    Console.WriteLine("b) 51");
    Console.WriteLine("c) 41");
    Console.WriteLine("d) 31");

    Console.ReadLine();
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer = a) Console.WriteLine("Well done");
    else Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer");
}
```

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the big checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
if (answer =  a)
```

to

```
if (answer ==  "a")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator (`=`) in your `if` statement here:

```
if (answer =  a)
```

From the looks of it, you want to compare what they are entering with a string of `a`, so you need to first use the comparison operator (`==`), and actually compare it to a string:

```
if (answer == "a")
    Console.WriteLine("Well done");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer");
```

Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you are using) should have really picked up this, since `a` is undeclared (or a `bool`).

---

In an unrelated note since the above was already answered, you can change your variable declaration and assignment here to be on the same line, since there is no need to separate the declaration and assignment.

```
string name = "";
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

to:

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: when I type in a, nothing happens, do you know why this is? But thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need type `a` then press enter, that's what `ReadLine()` does. You may want to consider using `ReadKey`, which will give you a `ConsoleKeyInfo` object, in this case change your `if` to `if (answer.KeyChar == 'a') {`.

Comment: I am pressing enter but nothing happens?

Comment: According to your code, after the answers are listed, you would need to hit enter once, *then* type `a` and enter again. You've called `ReadLine` twice (sorry I didn't notice this before).

Comment: Yes, the box *will* go away, once the program execution is done the box disappears. To avoid this you can add another `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your method. The best way of course is to not do that, and simply execute your program from `cmd`.

Comment: What is cmd? I am using c#.

Comment: ... Command Prompt. You're writing a console application. Console applications can run within a console, `cmd` is a console. Start -> Run `cmd`.

Comment: How could I then get it to add 1 to the score?

Comment: @user1993587 You should accept an answer to this question and ask another if you need help with another topic. That said, this is fairly basic and doesn't really warrant another question, you should consider reading up on C# basics. Please note also that SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.